# Construction of Real Number by Dedekind Cuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, axioms

I was studying Axiomatic Set Theory, and I have 2 questions about the construction of real numbers using Dedekind cut:

1. We  define a real number using the Dedekind cut: $x_{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ p \in \mathbb{Q}  | p < x \right \}$, how we can show that this set is unique, in other words, if we have $x_{\mathbb{R}} = y_{\mathbb{R}}$ how we can show that $x = y$.
2. We define the addition of two real numbers as: $x_{\mathbb{R}} + y_{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ q + r | q \in x_{\mathbb{R}} \wedge r \in y_{\mathbb{R}} \right \}$, how we can show that: $x_{\mathbb{R}} + y_{\mathbb{R}} = \left \{ p \in \mathbb{Q} | p < x + y\right \}$

Comment: That is not how real numbers are defined using Dedekind cuts: that would be circular, since you’d have to have the real number $x$ first before you could use it.

Comment: but I used the R index in order not to make a circular definition

Comment: I recommend going back and reading the precise definition of a Dedekind cut. The point of the definition is to define the real numbers starting from nothing but the rational numbers (in particular, no irrational numbers can be used in the definitions).

Comment: Changing the name does not make it any less circular: you still had to have the real number $x$ in order to define $x_{\Bbb R}$, so you’re not constructing the real numbers.

Comment: I wanted to summarize the idea by not writing the whole definition of Dedekind cut

Comment: The question *does* make sense when $x,y \in \mathbb Q$, in which case we're showing that (1) all the rational numbers "are" distinct real numbers, and (2) addition of real numbers agrees with addition of rational numbers. But you can't, for example, define $\sqrt2 = \{p \in \mathbb Q \mid p < \sqrt2\}$, because that's circular; you can define $\sqrt2 = \{p \in \mathbb Q \mid p^2 < 2\}$, and check that this satisfies the definition of a Dedekind cut.

Comment: One does not "summarize" something by making a false statement about it. Anyway, most people are able to define a Dedekind cut very quickly. It would have been easier to write the actual definition than to argue that you can "summarize" it. If you only care about the rational Dedekind cuts then they have the form you gave, but in that case you could have saved a lot of grief by saying you only cared about rational $x$ and $y.$

Comment: No I am asking about irrational Dedekind cut

Comment: I saw that notation to define rational Dedekind cut so I thought that it is true for irrational numbers too

Answer (score 1):

"I was studying Axiomatic Set Theory, and I have 2 questions about the construction of real numbers using Dedekind cut:

We define a real number using the Dedekind cut: xR={p∈Q|p<x},"

NO! We don't!!  A Dedekind cut is defined as any set of rational numbers that

1. is bounded above and
2. if x is in the set and y< x then y is also in the set.

It can be shown that if x is a rational number, then xR={p∈Q|p<x} is a Dedekind cut but the whole point us that there exist Dedekind cuts that are NOT of that form.
(If you allow x to be any real number then any Dedekind cut is of that form but obviously that cannot be used to **define** the real numbers!)

"how we can show that this set is unique, in other words, if weve xR=yR how we ca0n show that x=y."
Suppose x and y were not equal.  Then one is larger than the other and we can, without loss of generality, assume it is y: x< y.  Then there exist a rational number. p, such that x< p< y. That contradicts the assumption that xR= yR.

"We define the addition of two real numbers as: xR+yR={q+r|q∈xR∧r∈yR}, how we can show that: xR+yR={p∈Q|p<x+y}"

Again, that is not the definition of a Dedekind cut!
We prove, instead, that {q+r|q∈xR∧r∈yR} is a Dedekind cut by showing

1. Since xR is a Dedekind cut it has an upper bound, p, and since yR is a Dedekind cut it has an upper bound, q.  Then it follows that p+ q is an upper bound for {q+r|q∈xR∧r∈yR}.
2. If x is in {q+r|q∈xR∧r∈yR} then x= a+ b where a is in xR and b is in yR.  Then there exist u in xR, u< a and there exist v in yR, v< b so there exist y in {q+r|q∈xR∧r∈yR} such that y< x;

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, and for the last statement you make how we can show that if $p < x + y$ then their exist $q$ and $r$ such that $p = q+r$ and $q < x$ and $r <y$